# Accessing value in using key indexing

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have the dictionary `dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}`, how could I get the value of `a` by index like `dict[0]` or getting `dict[1] = 2` without using the explicite key? In fact, I would like to pass through that dictionary with a for loop in using index instead of explicit keys.

Comment: Use a Map. It will be sorted after insertion time, you can do `.values()[2]` ...

Comment: Object is not suited for such operations. You can use `Object.Keys` to get keys and the loop like an array, but properties in object are not sorted in a specific order. So you cannot guarantee the order of keys and access using it

Comment: Make an answer @Rajesh maybe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Object.keys(dict).map((key)=>{
console.log(dict[key])
})
```

Here we can go through all the keys in the object. And we can get the value of a particular key using `object[key]`.

Comment: Care to explain how OP solves his problem with this code snippet ?

Comment: Keys in object are not sorted. So you cannot guarantee the order of keys

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot. key value pairs are unordered inside the object. If you want to just ignore the key and care about positioning of value, you doesn't need objects and you need [Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

Answer (score 0):

Objects are Key - value pairs. These keys can be inserted/removed in any order. This makes using index to fetch keys inconsistent.

Also, properties of an object are not sorted in a particular order. So you cannot guarantee specific sequence to fetch using index.

Plus, you can have dynamic insertion/ deletions. So that will affect index based fetching.

All in all, its a bad idea to use Objects in this manner.

If you wish to use index based retrieval, you should use Arrays.

#### Reference:

- [Sort JavaScript object by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467129/sort-javascript-object-by-key)